# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).moveTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to programming. I am working on one my school assignment and I have two Jquery files that I am using. One was provided to us from the school. However I am keep getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).moveTo` is not a function. I have spent few hours on google but still have not manage to resolve this. Not sure what I am missing. Any suggestion ?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>


  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name='viewport'content='width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0 , user-scaleable=no'/>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" scr="./jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/introtoapps.min.js"></script>


      <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){            
        $("#balloon").moveTo(180);
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Why do you include query 2 times?

Comment: Remove any one of jquery file. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`  or `<script type="text/javascript" scr="./jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: what is "baloon"? as i know that, "moveTo" is a function about "window" type elements.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know moveTo function moves a window's left and top edge to the specified coordinates which require two parameter and your window object

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name='viewport'content='width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0 , user-scaleable=no'/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="./jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/introtoapps.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

window.moveTo(180, 180);
  });
  </script>
```